# Concurrent.futures used, but only one core is active

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to understand concurrent.futures so i wanted to create a small code example.
The numbers from 1 to $10^7$ shall be summed up. I want to use 4 cores. So I created 4 lists, namely
[1,5,9,13...], [2,6,10,14...], [3,7,11,...], [4,8,12,...].

But when I run my script and check the system monitor (Linux Mint 21) I see, that only one core is used. Shouldn't it be four?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import concurrent.futures

def computeSum(list):
    sumValue = 0
    for i in list:
        sumValue += i
    return sumValue

def computeModuloList(completeList, modulo, moduloOffset):
    # empty list
    moduloList = []
    for i in completeList:
        if i % modulo - moduloOffset == 0:
            moduloList.append(i) # append i to modulo list
    return moduloList



listToSum = range(1, 10**7+1)

partialList1 = computeModuloList(listToSum, 4, 0)
partialList2 = computeModuloList(listToSum, 4, 1)
partialList3 = computeModuloList(listToSum, 4, 2)
partialList4 = computeModuloList(listToSum, 4, 3)

partialLists = [partialList1, partialList2, partialList3, partialList4]

resultList = []

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    future = {executor.submit(computeSum, pList): pList for pList in partialLists}
    for completedFuture in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future):
        resultList.append(completedFuture.result())
            

allSum = 0
for result in resultList:
    allSum += result

print(str(allSum))
```

I checked the system monitor and only one core is used

Comment: You're submitting rather than mapping. Also, for CPU intensive work you should be using ProcessPoolExecutor. Also, if you want to make best use of the available cores you should compute the "modulo list" within the subprocess

Answer (score 0):

When you submit tasks to the ProcessPoolExecutor or ThreadPoolExecutor, they will be executed synchronously. However, if you use the map function, they will be executed in parallel.

This exercise is CPU bound and therefore not well suited to multi-threading.

The createModuloList function in the question is executed 4 times in sequence then each task (computeSum) is executed via the PoolExecutor hence only one additional core will be utilised.

In order to "stress" your CPU and to achieve the same mathematical outcome you could just do this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

RANGE = 1, 10**7+1
MODULO = 4
PROCS = 4

def computeSum(moduloOffset):
    moduloList = []
    for i in range(*RANGE):
        if i % MODULO - moduloOffset == 0:
            moduloList.append(i)
    return sum(moduloList)

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print(sum(executor.map(computeSum, range(PROCS))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
50000005000000
```

Comment: you seem quite knowledgeable.  Why not use the multiprocessing module (which would have been my suggestion) ?

Comment: @D.L I only used it because OP used concurrent.futures and may have a better understanding of that. A simple multiprocessing.Pool with apply_async would be better

Comment: i have posted the `multiprocessing` method (as an alternative), but also respectfully note this method...

Comment: i did a side-by-side test of both algos and interestingly the multiprocessing method is meaningfully faster for large numbers...

Comment: Ok, thank you all. Since I am just learning this stuff I guess I am just not far enough to code this :D

Answer (score 0):

I would go down the `multiprocessing` rout, but do note the answer from Codist which uses `concurrent.futures`.

This is what multiprocessing would look like for the same:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np


def main():
    n = 10**7
    arr = np.arange(1, n+1)

    # Split into 4 arrays 
    arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 = np.array_split(arr, 4)

    with Pool(4) as pool:
        res1 = pool.apply_async(sum_array, [arr1])
        res2 = pool.apply_async(sum_array, [arr2])
        res3 = pool.apply_async(sum_array, [arr3])
        res4 = pool.apply_async(sum_array, [arr4])

        sums = [r.get() for r in [res1, res2, res3, res4]]
    
    total = sum(sums)
    print(total)


def sum_array(arr):
    return np.sum(arr, dtype=np.uint64)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the code returns this:

```
50000005000000.0
```

As a side note. I ran both methods up to 10^9 and `multiprocessing` was meaningfully faster (in fact `concurrent.futures` hung my PC).